# Gmail adding hidden attribute to email images

Tags: html, css, image, email, gmail

I have an email template that I've uploaded to SendGrid. When I sent a test email to myself, I saw that out of three icon images to be displayed, only one was visible and other two were hidden. Turns out Gmail was adding "display: none !important;" and "hidden=''" attribute to two of the icons leaving out one for some reason.

Original HTML

```
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Twitter Icon" src="https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-twt.png">
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="LinkedIn Icon" src="https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-li.png">
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" alt="Facebook Icon" src="https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-fb.png">
```

How it looks in GMail

```
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: none !important;" alt="Twitter Icon" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/bSHlzCXnCJmZlsQOg6dE8OoJBbBDNTSwAQOMNle64t-SLXdoi9ZkiEhbUWoIAk7uAjw5Y6_JKfd3rFkWGp0yy2wUMYzP0MVUudfRqY2YGfC_IN4yU2mos0AV=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-twt.png" class="CToWUd" hidden="">
<img style="width:20px;height:20px" alt="LinkedIn Icon" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/XwPWKZwo3wA_-c1E0oieWC5NURlyWLo6sSh_kVUQLs6K1WwPiRDn_M9MP75oXhmTIr9qjY1e9aVvQvZ1yLjLM5Fg5uKHhvt30Q5wmtL35Rd3LPWVVo1_NUA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-li.png" class="CToWUd">
<img style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: none !important;" alt="Facebook Icon" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/kigqJy8mVUL8MSVTPBPQD5yx_PAm0_u0QTc_tGlS-QLnmmdg1i62TDwDYHV_XLqoJO8mdkaFsJWRKhRAufvoeEJ3IJiu1RRqcb1Wj8RFH4tVDz-v9rkHaoQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.xxxxxx.com/Content/img/sprites/icon-fb.png" class="CToWUd" hidden="">
```

Why does GMail hide two of my icons but leaves out one ? 
PS: My GMail settings allow download of all images by default.

Comment: Have you tried applying display:block !important; on the original html?

Comment: I haven't but what's bothering me is that why did gmail choose to hide two of the three similar img tags.

Comment: Its strange for sure. Try changing the image source as a test and see what happens maybe. I would also duplicate the 3 lines to maybe 20 and see if its always the same ones that are hidden. Im just brain storming here.